# Why does importing an SQL database into phpmyadmin create a 1050 error?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

`#1050 error - wp_taxonomymeta table already exists.`

This is the error I'm getting when I import my wordpress database into phpmyadmin. I've noticed that on my original database allocation, if I delete taxonomymeta table, it recreates itself.

If I delete `wp_options` table, this does not happen. Whats going on? I want to be able to export and import the db freely.

**EDIT:** I looked at the database structure of the original, checked wp_options, opened the dropdown box below and clicked repair table. Nothing seemed to happen. But I exported the sql file, then imported it into the new database and there were no more problems. I hope the website still works. Maybe this is an intermittent problem.

Comment: Please add ANY additional info by editing your question, not by adding answers.

Comment: I thought I had solved it, but thanks for your helpful contribution.

Comment: If you solved it, please post your answer